# Elastic: query_string proximity search between two sentences

Tags: database, elasticsearch, full-text-search, query-string, elastic-stack

Good morning,

I need to convert this old query (Exalead) to Elasticsearch:

```
"One Sentence" NEAR Word
```

I tried with:

```
"One Sentence" AND "Word"~16
```

But it interprets this query the same as:

```
"One Sentence" AND "Word"
```

and the distance between "One Sentence" and "Word" is more of 16 words.

Then how can i do this query with query_string_query?

Comment: in query string "One Sentence" AND "Word" means field should have these tokens anywhere  irespective of order or distance between them . ~ is used for fuzzy search and phrase_slop when you want to spcify maximum disctance between words in a phrase. What are you looking for in your result . Can you add sample document and expected result

Comment: i neet to find sencences like: "One sentence is better then a word", or "A word is one thousend times word that one sentence", for example. I need to find the sentences "one sentence" and "word" at the max distance of 16 words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [intervals query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html)

> Returns documents based on the order and proximity of matching terms.
>
> The intervals query uses matching rules, constructed from a small set
> of definitions. These rules are then applied to terms from a specified
> field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "intervals": {
      "text": {
        "all_of": {
          "ordered": false,
          "max_gaps": 16,  --> distance between both phrases
          "intervals": [
            {
              "match": {
                "query": "one sentence",
                "max_gaps": 0,--> distance between each phrase
                "ordered": false
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "query": "word",
                "max_gaps": 0,
                "ordered": false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Using query string**

> (Optional, integer) Maximum number of positions allowed between
> matching tokens for phrases. Defaults to 0. If 0, exact phrase matches
> are required. Transposed terms have a slop of 2.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "text",
            "query": "\"One sentence\""
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "text",
            "query": "\"sentence word\"",
            "phrase_slop": 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with query_string_query?

Comment: @DavideCavallini there is phrase_slop parameter in query string. It will account for distance with in a phrase ex "one word"  but you cant look for for distance between two phrases "one sentence" and "word". You can combine it in a should clause with phrase_slop 0 for  "one sentence" and  phrase_slop 16 for  "sentence word"

Comment: can you send me an example query?

Comment: @DavideCavallini I have added the query in answer.

Comment: is it possible to do this in a single query_string?

Comment: @DavideCavallini I went through its documentation. It checks for slop within a phrase, not within two phrases. Use Intervals or  you can search for phrase "one sentence word" which will return document even if "one" and "sentence" are not consecutive.